# TableView no data display in table after reimplementing QAbstractTableModel

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I cant get data to be shown on my QML TableView. I have defined two arrays - headers and rows which i want to be shown on TableView but with no success so far. Below is minimal reproducible example.

engine.py

```py
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql, QtQml
from Table import TbModel
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(TbModel, "TbModel", 1, 0, "TbModel")
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    qml_path = os.path.join( "main.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_path))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13
import TbModel 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    id: window
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    Grid {

    width: 300
    height: 100
    visible: true
    spacing: 200
    TableView
    {
        id: idtable
        model: TbModel { }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "sci" 
        title: "sci"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "year"
        title: "year"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "cont"
        title: "cont"
    }

        // Component.onCompleted: {

        //     var roles = model.roleNameArray()
        //                 for (var i = 0; i < model.columnCount(); i++)
        //     {
        //         var column = addColumn( Qt.createQmlObject(
        //             "import QtQuick.Controls 1.1; TableViewColumn {}",
        //             this) )
        //         column.role=roles[i]
        //         column.title=roles[i]

        //     }
        // }
    }

}
}
```

Table.py

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex, QObject, Qt
from PySide2 import QtCore

class TbModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent: QObject = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.headers = ["sci", "year", "cont"]
        self.rows =    [("Newton", "1643-01-04", "Classical mechanics"),
           ("Einstein", "1879-03-14", "Relativity"),
           ("Darwin", "1809-02-12", "Evolution")]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.rows)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.headers)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        return self.rows[index.row()][index.column()]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role) :
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

        if section < 0 or section >= len(self.headers):
            return None

        return self.headers[section]

    def roleNames(self):
        roles = {
            Qt.UserRole + 1 : 'sci',
            Qt.UserRole + 2 : 'year',
            Qt.UserRole + 3 : 'cont'
        }
        return roles


    @QtCore.Slot(result="QVariantList")
    def roleNameArray(self):
        names = []
        names=self.headers

        return names
```

I can select rows in TableView but I can't see data. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I just look at [C++ example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#details). Didn't you try to implement `QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override` and its usage as described in the example? In some python way, of course. I mean just replace the delegate with `Text { text: display }`? Also I would try to replace role name to some symbols instead of numbers.

Comment: i think you are right, I edited code with implementing roleNames()  and manual inserting TableColumns, but still table is empty.

Comment: I guess you have to update`data()` as well. I mean that appropriate value should be returned for each role. Now you ignore all the roles except `Qt.DisplayRole` but in some time you declare roles >= Qt.UserRole + 1. The same for `headerData()`.

Comment: I implemented your solution, it helped to some extend. I get data written to table, but only data from first row `Newton` , `Einstein` , `Darwin` written in all 3 columns. I tried to figure out this myself, that is why delay in feedback. Code with implemented solution is edited in question.

Comment: @user2727167 1) If a solution is incorrect then you need immediate feedback since the solution is not only for you but for the entire community. 2) If you have a solution, don't put it in your question but create an answer. please use `@username`. So I made a rollback, on the other hand your edition clearly implements my solution, what was the difference between your solution and mine? Read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour]

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry about that. I don't have solution. Just wanted to change code with your update. With your answer implemented I get: [link](https://imgur.com/3OQFhbZ) . I need to have other 2 columns shown as well. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has 2 errors:

- In C++ `roleNames()` method returns a `QHash<int, QByteArray>` so in Python you must return a dictionary whose key is an integer and value must be a `bytes` or `QByteArray` but in your case the value is a string.
- The data method must provide the information required by the view, and in this case they are the roles associated with "sci", "year" and "cont" whose values are `Qt.UserRole + 1`, `Qt.UserRole + 2` and `Qt.UserRole + 3` that are different from `Qt.DisplayRole`, but in your logic any value other than `Qt.DisplayRole` will be None contradicting the above.
- QML offers several TableView: [QtQuick.Controls 1.x](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html) and [QtQuick](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html). In your case you are using the first one that does not require as a model a QAbstractTableModel but only a QAbstractListModel since the QModelIndex used by the view will always have the value of the column at 1.
- Considering the above, you may have problems since QML offers several items with the same name that belong to different packages, to solve this problem the namespace is used.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, QObject, Qt, Slot


class TbModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent: QObject = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.headers = ["sci", "year", "cont"]
        self.rows = [
            ("Newton", "1643-01-04", "Classical mechanics"),
            ("Einstein", "1879-03-14", "Relativity"),
            ("Darwin", "1809-02-12", "Evolution"),
        ]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.rows)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        if 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
            if role in self.roleNames():
                name_role = self.roleNames()[role].decode()
                col = self.headers.index(name_role)
                return self.rows[row][col]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and 0 <= section < len(self.headers):
            return self.headers[section]

    def roleNames(self):
        roles = {}
        for i, header in enumerate(self.headers):
            roles[Qt.UserRole + i + 1] = header.encode()
        return roles

    @Slot(result="QVariantList")
    def roleNameArray(self):
        return self.headers
```

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as QQC1

import TbModel 1.0

QQC1.ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height

    QQC1.TableView
    {
        id: idtable
        width: 600
        height: 300
        model: TbModel{ }
        QQC1.TableViewColumn {
            role: "sci" 
            title: "sci"
        }
        QQC1.TableViewColumn {
            role: "year"
            title: "year"
        }
        QQC1.TableViewColumn {
            role: "cont"
            title: "cont"
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]